# Get the Id of an object in the standard controller without an extension?

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller

Is it possible to get the Id of an object in a Visualforce page without a controller extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to put the object API name and .Id in a formula expression holder? such as:

```
"{!Opportunity.Id}"
```

which you can put anywhere in a Visualforce page?

Comment: Yeah, realized how obvious this answer was right after I posted, thanks for helping me through my not-yet-caffienated morning

Comment: Well, as a concise question and answer pair, it will remain on google for future searchers to find at least!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the merge field syntax. For example if you are using the `Opportunity` standard controller you can use `{!opportunity.Id}` in your Visualforce page.